# How to make "OR" condition using a JavaScript method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, conditional-statements

I'm learning functional programming and trying to avoid using statements.

I have a long condition statement seen below:

```
if (!event.body || 
  !event.body.Id || 
  !event.body.source.accountId || 
  !event.body.sourceId || !event.body.targetId || 
  !event.body.targetName) 
{ return 0; }
```

I'm thinking of doing something like:

```
let invalid = [event.body, event.body.Id, event.body.source.accountId, event.body.sourceId, event.body.targetId, event.body.targetName]

if(invalid.includes("")){return 0;}
```

but I'm not sure about using `""` and `!`, are they the same? I know `!` means `null` or `undefined`, but not sure `""` empty string will do here?

Another way I can think of is:

```
let invalid = [event.body, event.body.Id, event.body.source.accountId, event.body.sourceId, event.body.targetId, event.body.targetName]

if(invalid.every(x=>{if(x){return x}})){return 0;}
```

I'm not sure which method is better?

Comment: what would you like to check? is zero a valid value (for an id)?

Comment: some() is what you want

Answer (score 2):

`includes("")` won't detect `null`, `undefined`, `false`, `0` and `NaN`, just`""`. Therefore using `every` is better here:

```
if(!invalid.every(x => x))
```

or the same with `some`:

```
if(invalid.some(x => !x))
```

Comment: The way the array is named (`invalid`) it makes me believe it should be `x => !x` instead

Comment: @adelin close, but yes I had to improve a bit :)

Answer (score 2):

Note that `!a || !b` is equivalent to `!(a && b)`.

So, consider this:

```
const isValid = event => event.body && event.body.Id && event.body.source.accountId ....

if(!isValid(event)){
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Off-topic here, but: Why use a function instead of a boolean for `isValid`?

Comment: you said you want a more functional approach...
what if you'll need to verify the event validity in other places?

Comment: I'm not the OP but ok ;)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm thinking can I do like
>
> ```
> let invalid = [event.body, event.body.Id, event.body.source.accountId, event.body.sourceId, event.body.targetId, event.body.targetName]
>
> if(invalid.includes("")){return 0;}
> ```

This works, but *only if the values are always strings*. For instance, if `event.body.Id` is `null` or `undefined` (or another falsy value that isn't exactly `""`), it will still go through.

> Another way I can think is
>
> ```
> let invalid = [event.body, event.body.Id, event.body.source.accountId, event.body.sourceId, event.body.targetId, event.body.targetName]
>
> if(invalid.every(x=>{if(x){return x}})){return 0;}
> ```

This also works, but it uses an `if` statement, which isn't considered very functional.

**My Suggestion:**

Do

```
let invalid = [event.body, event.body.Id, event.body.source.accountId, event.body.sourceId, event.body.targetId, event.body.targetName]

return (invalid.every(x => x) ? 1 : 0)
```

Using `invalid.every(x => x)` avoids the `if` statement and will properly handle all falsy values. And the ternary makes it return either 1 or zero, without the use of an `if`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) like this:

```
let invalid = [event.body, event.body.Id, event.body.source.accountId, event.body.sourceId, event.body.targetId, event.body.targetName]

invalid.every(e => e)
```